# Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for AuthHttp! ; Zone: angular in angular2-jwt

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-jwt

dashboard.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

constructor (private http: Http,private authHttp: AuthHttp) {}
```

When I do this it gives an error `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: DI`

app.module.ts

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AuthModule } from 'angular2-jwt';
.
imports: [
  HttpModule,
  AuthModule   
],
```

How I resolve this?

Comment: Have you imported the httpmodule in your ngmodule? Have you set AuthHttp as a provider in your ngModule? :)

Comment: I update my question and add app.module.ts

Comment: Have you looked at the `basic configuration` here: https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
import { AUTH_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2-jwt';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        ...AUTH_PROVIDERS,
        // other providers
    ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**option 2**

```
import { AuthModule, AuthConfigConsts} from 'angular2-jwt';

const authConfig: IAuthConfig = {
    headerName: AuthConfigConsts.DEFAULT_HEADER_NAME, // change to your header name
    headerPrefix: AuthConfigConsts.HEADER_PREFIX_BEARER, // or null or something else
    tokenName: AuthConfigConsts.DEFAULT_TOKEN_NAME, // change to your token name
    tokenGetter: () => localStorage.getItem(authConfig.tokenName) as string,
    noJwtError: false,
    noClientCheck: false,
    globalHeaders: [],
    noTokenScheme: false
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        AuthModule.forRoot(authConfig)
    ],
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: wait a minutes!

Comment: angular2-jwt"' has no exported member 'AuthConfigDefaults'.)

Comment: i'll checkout option 2 later

Comment: hey man, could you please try option 2 again, i've made some changes.